# Como verificar se o dispositivo possui botões virtuais?

Tags: android

Como identificar dispositivos que possuam botões virtuais para assim tratar o espaço que eles ocupam na tela ?

Comment: Se realmente precisa disto para tratar os espaços, então seu app deve ter muitos problemas por ter altura fixa, creio que muita coisa vc pode resolver ajustando o layout ou colocando uma simples scrollbar e deixando o navigation fixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o dispositivo tem o botão "virtual" usando o [hasPermanentMenuKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29) do Android.

Exemplo:

```
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey(); // retorna true | false
```

Comment: Deu falto no Moto E 2ª Geração, mas não séria pra dar true ?

Comment: Para complementar a resposta http://stackoverflow.com/a/13530426/1518921